# Problems with youtube API function

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I am looking for a way to have `player.getDuration()` and `player.getCurrentTime()` from [youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), written in normal time (Minute:Seconds) Like this bellow:

```
var mind = player.getCurrentTime() /*or player.getDuration()*/  % (60 * 60);
var m = Math.floor(mind / 60);

var secd = mind % 60;
var s = Math.ceil(secd)

document.write(m,":",s); seconds;
```

But it keeps sending an error `NaN:NaN`

Also I want to change an image when the video has finished using the function `YT.PlayerState.ENDED` like this:

```
if(YT.PlayerState.ENDED){
 $("#change").attr('src', "../play button.png");
             }
```

But it is not working?

Comment: Please ask only one question per question -- i.e., move the part about reacting to the PlayerState to a new question.

Comment: Your minutes/seconds calculation looks alright, so it probably fails because it doesn't get proper input data. Have you checked the value of `player.getCurrentTime()` and whether `player` even is the object you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely player is not properly set.
Also, the value of getCurrentTime() changes during playing; put the code in a function which you call every second.
Maybe use jquery.min.js to display the value.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var player;  // Reference to global player object.

// call the function every 1 second.
setInterval(displTime,1000);  // PUT THIS STATEMENT JUST AFTER THE PLAYER HAS BEEN CREATED. 

function displTime() {
if (! player)
   alert("NO player object !");  // Check if player has been set. 
// player.getCurrentTime() or player.getDuration()
var mind = player.getCurrentTime();   // returns elapsed time in seconds 
var m = Math.floor(mind / 60);
var secd = mind % 60;
var s = Math.ceil(secd)
$("#pt").html(m + ":" + s);  // Using the JQUERY library to write to body
}
     </script>



          <div id="pt"></div>    <!-- Put this in the html BODY to display m:s -->
```

Comment: It can't seem to find the player object? I am using the code from this for the player https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#polling_the_player

Comment: I used player as reference to the player object, since that was in your question. Looking at the example code, you can see it makes the reference to the player object with: ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytPlayer"); The var to use is here ytplayer. But also it's a local var since it's inside a function. It works because updatePlayerInfo(); is in the same function as ytplayer.

Comment: Yes sorry. So what do I need to change in your answer? Thanks

Comment: From the start of your example code https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#polling_the_player REPLACE 1 line: "updateHTML("videoCurrentTime", ytplayer.getCurrentTime());" by the following 6 statements:       var mind = ytplayer.getCurrentTime();
var m = Math.floor(mind / 60);
var secd = mind % 60;
var s = Math.ceil(secd);
var displMS = m + ":" + s;
updateHTML("videoCurrentTime", displMS);

Comment: That is great! thank you! when `ytplayer.getCurrentTime()` = a number like 62 it comes out as 1:2 instead of 1:02 and 65 comes out as 1:5 instead of 1:05 have you got any ideas on how you might be able to change this?

Comment: You check the value and add a prefix zero. For example, replace the previous 6 statements with these 8 statements:                    var mind = ytplayer.getCurrentTime();
var m = Math.floor(mind / 60);
if (m < 10) var preM = "0"; else var preM = "";
var secd = mind % 60;
var s = Math.ceil(secd);
if (s < 10) var preS = "0"; else var preS = "";
var displMS = preM + m + ":" + preS + s;
updateHTML("videoCurrentTime", displMS);

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you call these function when the video has been loaded or else it will be NaN. Just alert(player.getCurrentTime()); and see what the output is.

-

Your if statment if wrong. You are comparing ENDED with nothing. See this for an example

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this: 

    `function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      $("#change").attr('src', "../play button.png");
      ytplayer.seekTo(0, false);
        ytplayer.stopVideo();
        }
    }`

But unfortunately it is still not working?

Comment: Maybe you created the player in a different way and YT does not exist ? Try replacing YT.PlayerState.ENDED by 0 (since 0 the value of "end of playing".

Comment: still no luck I also tried `if (ytplayer.getCurrentTime() === ytplayer.getDuration()) {}`

Comment: Check first, if you see the alert when the video has ended: function onPlayerStateChange(event) { if (event.data == 0) { alert("video is has ended"); } }

Comment: no not working! this is the code I have used  code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#polling_the_player

Comment: The example uses newState instead of event, where newState equals event.data. Assuming the function code is still original, replace the code of "onPlayerStateChange" by:                                    function onPlayerStateChange(newState) {
        updateHTML("playerState", newState);
        if (newState == 0) { alert("video has ended");}
      }                                                          Then, if you see the alert at the end of the video, replace it with your own code; with whatever action you want when the video ends.

Comment: No it is not giving the alert! I am confused as to why this is not working!! Everything seems correct!

Comment: it is because you did only two "=" signs it should be 3 :) Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @user2768038 Your welcome. I copied the given example code and only modified those few lines. Yes, i use two "=", but i do see the alert. However i did not tested every Browser. I use the Chrome & FireFox Browsers. Using 3 "=" will also match the type. In your case it must have evaluated it to "FALSE".

Comment: @Als Can I ask. How do you know that there is an error? I am using dreamweaver and it doesn't give an error if I use two?

Comment: @user2768038 I did not say there is an error. There is a difference in using "==" or "===". But with the 2 browsers i use, it makes NO DIFFERENCE: both work for me. With that code the alert should come when newState equals zero, because then it becomes TRUE. However, if evaluated to zero, it is seen as FALSE. (I don't know about dreamweaver, but it's not a browser. Note that using === also works in the 2 browsers i use.)